# How to add event listener with function callback in html inside a class?

Tags: javascript, class, addeventlistener

Imagine having a class that generates content on the page. Part of the content should have event listener attached in html such as `onclick=function()`.

How can I make sure to call the function from within the class that constructed the html?

```
class Container {
  constructor(hook) {
    this.hook = "#" + hook;
    this.addDiv = this.addDiv.bind(this);
    this.fireMe = this.fireMe.bind(this);
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.init();
  }
  addDiv() {
    const div = `<div onclick="fireMe()">FIRE ME</div>`;
    document.querySelector(this.hook).innerHTML = div;
  }
  fireMe() {
    console.log("hello!");
  }
  init() {
    this.addDiv();
  }
}

let div = new Container("app");
```

now getting error that fireMe is undefined (which is right because it is not available in global scope).

I know I can add event listener by rendering the div first and than adding the event listener, but is there a way of adding event listener from within `<div>` tag to actually reach `Container.fireMe()` method?

Comment: Events inline in the `DOM` look for the function to be declared in the *global scope*. Use an event listener instead. Also, I'd suggest creating the `<div>` as an *element* instead of using an HTML string and `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that would be the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the element -> something like this

```js
class Container {
  constructor (hook) {
    this.hook = '#' + hook;
    this.addDiv = this.addDiv.bind(this);
    this.fireMe = this.fireMe.bind(this);
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.init();
  }

  addDiv () {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = 'FIRE ME';
    div.addEventListener('click', this.fireMe );
    document.querySelector(this.hook).innerHTML = div;
  }

  fireMe () {
    console.log('hello!');
  }

  init () {
    this.addDiv();
  }
}

const div = new Container('app');
```

Comment: Because i am flexibler, if i want add parameter

Comment: God forbid treating functions like first class citizens ;)

Answer (score 2):

Never use inline event handlers as there are [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) to avoid this 20+ year old technique that just will not die.

Instead, use modern, standards-based code with [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). If you do this along with making the new HTML using the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), you'll be able to more easily accomplish your goal:

```
addDiv() {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textConent = "FIRE ME";
  div.addEventListener("click", this.fireMe);
  document.querySelector(this.hook).innerHTML = div;
}
```

Comment: [Three guesses as to why it will not die... :)](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)

Comment: @ChrisG Oh, I know. That's why I get on my soap box.

Answer (score 0):

You should create elements use `document.createElement()` rather than using string

```
class Container {
  constructor(hook) {
    this.hook = "#" + hook;
    this.addDiv = this.addDiv.bind(this);
    this.fireMe = this.fireMe.bind(this);
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    this.init();
  }
  addDiv(){
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "Fire Me";
    div.addEventListener("click",this.fireMe);
    document.querySelector(this.hook).appendChild(div);
  }
  fireMe() {
    console.log("hello!");
  }
  init() {
    this.addDiv();
  }
}
let div = new Container("app");
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(this.hook).appendChild(div);` will add the node to the element, where the OP is replacing the current node with a new one.